# TypeError: Cannot read property 'args' when creating spy with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, tdd, jasmine, bdd

I'm following along with a tutorial from the Backbone Fundamentals book (http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#jasmine) and am trying to create a spy in order to test validation.

The code below produces the following error in my SpecRunner:

'TypeError: Cannot read property 'args' of undefined'

```
it('Can contain custom validation rules, and will trigger an invalid event on failed validation.', function() {

    var errorCallback = jasmine.createSpy('-invalid event callback-');

    var todo = new Todo();

    todo.on('invalid', errorCallback);

    todo.set({done:'a non-boolean value'});

    var errorArgs = errorCallback.mostRecentCall.args;

    expect(errorArgs).toBeDefined();
    expect(errorArgs[0]).toBe(todo);
    expect(errorArgs[1]).toBe('Todo.done must be a boolean value.');
});
```

I've searched high and low with little results. I've also tried replacing:

```
var errorArgs = errorCallback.mostRecentCall.args;
```

with:

```
var errorArgs = errorCallback.calls.mostRecent();
```

which seems is what's being used in the jasmine docs, but still same problem.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial you linked to is using Jasmine 1.3, and you're probably using [Jasmine 2.0](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html). The syntax for spies changed quite a bit.

The line you're looking for is

```
var errorArgs = errorCallback.calls.mostRecent().args;
```

Or alternatively,

```
var errorArgs = errorCallback.calls.argsFor(0);
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'll check this out this evening when I get home.